# Function to return a combined observable when one can be undefined

Tags: javascript, rxjs

can someone advise if there is a better/elegant way of writing the following code to return an observable. That one observable I have an if condition for is optional.

Thanks!

```
  addPoints(
    pointsDTO: PointsDTO,
    userId: string
  ): Observable<profile> {

    let addPoints$: Observable<profile>, deletePoints$: Observable<profile>;

    addPoints$ = this.applyPoints(userId, pointsDTO);

    deletePoints$ = this.removePoints(userId, pointsDTO);

    if (deletePoints$) {
      return concat(deletePoints$, addPoints$).pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.getProfile(userId).pipe(catchError()))
      ),
    } else {
      return addPoints$.pipe(
       switchMap(() => this.getProfile(userId).pipe(catchError())
      ),
    }
  }
```

Comment: Looking at your code, your deletePoints$ observable will always be undefined. You only assign a value to it in if condition and in this case, you'll never enter in that block. It's difficult to give you a solution without understanding the requirements.

Comment: @ionut-t sorry I had the wrong version up there. So  that DTO holds a certain value and based on that points will be deleted and we get back an observable otherwise it will be undefined.

Comment: at first I just had this but ofcourse I get an error when that deletePoints$ is undefined.
return concat(deletePoints$, addPoints$).pipe(
        switchMap(() => this.getProfile(userId).pipe(catchError()))
      )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EMPTY` that won't affect `concat()` functionality. `EMPTY` just emits one `complete` notification and no `next`s so `concat()` will just continue with the next source Observable:

```
return concat(deletePoints$ || EMPTY, addPoints$).pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.getProfile(userId).pipe(catchError())),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

RxJS steams involve *emitting* items over time. That means that you can't `if` them after they are set to determine if they have a value. Instead, you need to `pipe` them through a set of operators.

Try something like this:
addPoints$ = this.applyPoints(userId, pointsDTO);

```
deletePoints$ = this.removePoints(userId, pointsDTO);

return merge(deletePoints$, addPoints$).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.getProfile(userId).pipe(catchError()))
}
```

This uses `merge` instead of `concat` and should work fine if `deletePoints$` doesn't emit anything.

But as the other commenter said, I'm not clear on what you are trying to do here, so this may not be the solution you need. Also, I assume there is something subscribing to these streams somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm new to observables so yes I can give merge a try. Not much else happening except for the front end making a request to the controller and then this function is called in the service.

Comment: Do want to mention the applyPoints and removePoints have the same return type but are two different streams that are not dependent on each other and from what I had read thought concat was good to use for such a case

Comment: If you'd like some rxjs learning resources, you can find some here: https://dev.to/angular/links-to-my-content-2med

Comment: Thanks for sharing. merge did not work for me. It won't take undefined as a value  whereas the solution above by Martin worked.